# How to say grandparents (as in the collective group) rather than the specific individual?

Tags: translation

I feel like there must be an answer to this question. I know each of the individual titles

> 外公，外婆，爷爷，奶奶

but I can't seem to find how to say a collective title 'grandparents' as we would use in English, nor will my dictionary turn up a good answer.

Can anyone tell me if there is a proper way to say grandparents in Chinese?

Comment: The best I can say is 祖父母 & 外祖父母.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[祖父母](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%A5%96%E7%88%B6%E6%AF%8D)**

> 祖父母是指父亲的父母亲，又称“爷爷、嫲嫲”、“爷爷、奶奶”。母亲的父母称为外祖父母，在中国南方称为外公、外婆，在中国北方则称为姥姥（或姥娘）、姥爷。自己则分别是祖父母和外祖父母的孙儿或孙女、外孙或外孙女。

It also links to the English page for [Grandparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandparent).

---

[National Grandparents Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Grandparents_Day) is also translated as:

> [祖父母节](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%A5%96%E7%88%B6%E6%AF%8D%E7%AF%80)

Answer (score 0):

- 外公，外婆 are the parents of your mum. You call them 外祖父母.
- 爷爷，奶奶 are the parents of your dad. You call them 祖父母.

Understand?